# How to prove that $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^3y}{x^4+y^2} = 0?$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

> How to prove that $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \dfrac{x^3y}{x^4+y^2} = 0?$

First I tried to contradict by using $y = mx$ , but I found that the limit exists.

Secondly I tried to use polar coordinates, $x =  \cos\theta $ and $y = \sin\theta$,

And failed .. How would you prove this limit equals $0$?

Comment: how did you not get the limit of 0 for the y=mx case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With polar coordinates we're cool, too:

$$x=r\cos\theta\;\;,\;\;y=r\sin\theta$$

$$\frac{x^3y}{x^4+y^2}=\frac{r^4\cos^3\theta\sin\theta}{r^4\cos^4\theta+r^2\sin^2\theta}=\frac{r^2\cos^3\theta\sin\theta}{r^2\cos^4\theta+\sin^2\theta}\xrightarrow[r\to 0]{}\frac0{0+\sin^2\theta}=0$$

But what if $\;\sin^2\theta=0\;$ ? Well, then *also* $\;\sin\theta=0\;$ and the first expression above's already zero from the beginning...

Comment: -1. This isn't a correct argument, since it would also “prove” that $x^2 y/(x^4+y^2) \to 0$, which is *false* (since $x^2 y/(x^4+y^2) = 1/2$ for $y=x^2 \neq 0$). The problem is that you can't treat $\theta$ as a constant when letting $r \to 0$.

Answer (score 6):

Note that, when $x$ and $y$ are both less than $1$, we have

$\displaystyle \left|\frac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2}\right| < \frac{1}{2}$

multiplying by $|x|$ we get

$\displaystyle \left|\frac{x^3y}{x^4+y^2}\right| < \frac{1}{2}|x|$

Result follows from squeeze theorem

Comment: You need $\le$, not $<$ (as shown by taking $y=x$). Also, you should explain how you derive the estimate. How is it relevant that $|x|<1$ and $|y|<1$ (I assume that you meant absolute values here)?

Answer (score 4):

Cauchy inequality:
$$x^4+y^2\ge 2 x^2 |y|$$

Thus
$$
\left|\frac{x^3y}{x^2+y^4}\right|\le \frac{|x|}{2}.
$$
But the RHS tends to $0$ as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$, and hence
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^3y}{x^2+y^4}=0.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $x^4 + y^2 \geq |x^2y|$  (for instance, because $x^4+y^2+2x^2y = (x^2+y)^2\geq0$ and $x^4+y^2-2x^2y = (x^2-y)^2 \geq0$).  Hence $\displaystyle \left|\frac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2}\right| \leq 1$ when $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ and thus $$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \left|\frac{x^3y}{x^4+y^2}\right| \leq \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)} |x| = 0,$$ so the limit is 0 by the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=kx^2$, then the expression is $\frac{kx}{1+k^2}$.
$|\frac{k}{1+k^2}|\leq 1/2$ so the expression is bounded by $|x/2|$.  The path along $x=0$ can be done separately.

Comment: Would this actually prove that the limit is zero?

Comment: no, the limit has only been shown along some family of curves.