# Prove $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^3y}{x^4+y^2} = 0$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, arithmetic

How would you prove the following limit?

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^3y}{x^4+y^2} = 0$$

I think the best way is using the squeeze theorem but I can't find left expression.

$$0 \le \frac{x^3y}{x^4 + y^2} \le \frac{x^3y}{x^4} \le \frac{x^3y}{x^3} \le y = 0.$$

But I'm not sure I'm right (especially at $\frac{x^3y}{x^4} \le \frac{x^3y}{x^3}).$

If I'm right - I'd glad if you can accept it.

If I'm wrong - can you please correct me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/637987/how-to-prove-that-lim-x-y-to-0-0-fracx3yx4y2-0

Comment: Also, if $0 < x < 1$, then $x^4 < x^3$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch to polar coordinates, $x = r \times \cos \theta$, $y = r \times \sin \theta$. Then your limit will be

$r^2 \times \frac{\cos^3 \theta \sin\theta}{r^2\cos^4\theta + \sin^2\theta}$
for $r \to 0$ and an arbitrary $\theta$ path, which is a product of a term going to zero and a finite fraction and hence goes to zero

Comment: The path is actually arbitrary, since $\theta$ can be a function of $r$ - no restrictions implied. The idea is that the ratio term is bound (denominator being a sum of positive terms) regardless of the path function $\theta(r)$, so the limit exists and is zero.

Comment: @TooOldForMath I don't see the flaw in the logic either.  The points on any path can be expressed as $(x,y) = (r \cos\theta, r \sin\theta)$.  If the path approaches to the origin, then the radius $r$ from origin must tend to $0$.  As huh says, we are not fixing $\theta$, so we are not just considering lines.  I've often used polar coordinates to evaluate multivariable limits, and I certainly hope I haven't been doing it wrong for years!

Comment: @SpamIam and huh I'm sorry, I made a mistake :-). See my name.

Comment: I just thought I saw the usual mistake, which is so often made, where in this case it is completely fine to use polar coordinates, as you have of course explained correctly.

Comment: It appears that you are using $r^2$ as the "term going to zero" and $\frac{\cos^3(\theta)\sin(\theta)}{r^2\cos^4(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta)}$ as the "finite fraction". However, along the path $r=\sin(\theta)$, the "finite fraction" is unbounded.

Answer (score 3):

Since $|2ab|\le a^2+b^2$,
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{x^3y}{x^4+y^2}\right|
&=|x|\,\left|\frac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2}\right|\\
&\le\frac12|x|
\end{align}
$$
using $a=x^2$ and $b=y$.

Answer (score 1):

alternately, bracket your limit using its negative and positive absolute value. Since your inequalities show the absolute value going to zero, the lower bracket will go to zero as well.

Comment: Why post two answers?