# Does the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x^3y^2}{x^6+y^4}$ exists?

Tags: calculus

I was trying to find if the the following limit exists:
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x^3y^2}{x^6+y^4}
$$
From [this topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/637987/how-to-prove-that-lim-x-y-to-0-0-fracx3yx4y2-0) I tried to switch to polar coordinates:
$$
\frac{x^3y^2}{x^6+y^4}=\frac{r^3\cos^3\theta\cdot r^2\sin^2\theta}{r^6\cos^6\theta+r^4\sin^4\theta}=\frac{r\cos^3\theta\sin^2\theta}{r^2\cos^6\theta+\sin^4\theta}\to 0
$$
But apparently this limit does not exists (proved it in another way). Why this method worked for the limit in that topic and here it didn't work?

Comment: A comment on the linked answer using polar coordinates explains it is not a valid proof. It's an incorrect technique which in that case happened to give the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the path along the x-axis, y-axis and $y=x^{\frac{3}{2}}$.

Along the x-axis:
$$\lim_{(x,0) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^3 \cdot 0}{x^6 +  0}=0
$$

Along the y-axis:$$\lim_{(0,x) \to (0,0)} \frac{0 \cdot y^2}{0 +  y^4}=0
$$

Along the curve $y=x^{\frac{3}{2}}$:
$$ \lim_{(x,x^{\frac{3}{2}}) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^3{(x^{\frac{3}{2}})}^2}{x^6 + {(x^{\frac{3}{2}})}^4 }=\frac{x^6}{2x^6}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Therefore, the limit does not exist.

Comment: That's how I proved it does not exists. I know it does not exists. My question is why the converting to polar coordinates didn't work like it did in that other topic?

Comment: I believe that you're not supposed to treat $\theta$ as a constant.  Are you supposed to use polar coordinates for this problem?  Using the xy coordinate system is faster, easier, and more reliable.

Comment: Just trying to understand why it didn't work and why it worked for them. They did treat it as a constant, then why their answer is correct?

Comment: @vesii The answer is correct, but the proof is not. Like the classic "to simplify $16/64$, cancel the sixes".

Comment: The method does not work in this case, because at some point you conclude that the second term in the denominator is the dominant term. Taking the limit of r to zero then yields zero. However, you can take a different path to the origin in such a way that the first term in the denominator is dominant. This leads to a different result. And therefore we must conclude that the limit does not exist.

Comment: @aschepler Why is this proof incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

The conversion to polar coordinates has not failed.  Note what happens when $r=\tan^2(\theta)\sec(\theta)$, $|\theta| > \pi/2$.  Then,

$$\frac{r\cos^3(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)}{r^2\cos^6(\theta)+\sin^4(\theta)}=\frac{\sin^4(\theta)}{2\sin^4(\theta)}=\frac12$$

And of course, if $\theta =0$ or $\theta =\pi/2$, then

$$\frac{r\cos^3(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)}{r^2\cos^6(\theta)+\sin^4(\theta)}=0$$

---

**EXPLANATION:  So what is happening here?**

Note that $x^6+y^4\ge 2\sqrt{x^6y^4}=2|x|^3y^2$, with equality for $y^2=|x|^3$. Therefore, we have

$$\left|\frac{x^3y^2}{x^6+y^4}\right|\le \frac12$$

with equality when $y^2=|x|^3$.

If we transform to polar coordinates, this analysis is identical to

$$\left|\frac{r\cos^3(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)}{r^2\cos^6(\theta)+\sin^4(\theta)}\right|\le \left|\frac{r\cos^3(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)}{2\sqrt{r^2\cos^6(\theta)\sin^4(\theta)}}\right|=\frac12$$

with equality when $r=\frac{\sin^2(\theta)}{|\cos^3(\theta)|}=\tan^2(\theta)|\sec(\theta)|$.

Comment: @vesii Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. If it was not useful, then I can simply delete this answer if you prefer.